# Fetching key-value by position from dictionary

Tags: python

I use a python  dictionary  tel = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139.....,'john':5147} 
Is there any way to fetch all the values located between index range?
for example, all values located from the 5th-10th position...

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 6):

There are no indexes/positions in a python dictionary. Key/value pairs do not have any specific order.

If you want to select specific positions from the dictionary, you have to give it some criteria/order.

For example, according to alphabetical order of names:

```
sorted(tel.items())[5:11]
```

returns a list of 5 tuples of `(name, number)` from the positions 5-10 in the **alphabetical** order.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be referencing Python dictionaries by index. Python dictionaries order of storage of items is arbitrary and denoting it by index is bound to fail. Instead you use reference it by `keys` whenever it comes to dictionaries. When it comes to Ordered Dict, the standard libraries collections.OrderedDict does not seem to provide index method, but, there are certain OrderedDict [odict](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html), where you can reference elements using index.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.

```
>>> tel = {'tel_1': 111, 'tel_2': 222, 'tel_3': 333, 'tel_4': 444} 
         
>>> for i in range(len(tel)):
>>>    key = list(tel.keys())[i]
>>>    print(key, ': ', tel[key])

tel_1 :  111
tel_2 :  222
tel_3 :  333
tel_4 :  444
```

Somewhat cumbersome, however